# Using SUMMARIZE to Count Values for a Range of Dates

Tags: dax

I am trying to use SUMMARIZE to generate a table containing a list of people (represented by Phishing[Zid]) and the number of times where the person had a "Phishing Outcome" of "Fail" for a 12 month period. The 12 month period for each person will start on the date represented by Calendar[Month Index] and then I want to count the failures between that month index and month index - 11.

For example, assume the current row in the Phishing table has a Zid of wzqc51 and Calendar[Month Index] = 27. In the CALCULATE function I want to count the number of fails for month index between 16 and 27. It's the piece in angle brackets below that I cannot get right.

Also, there is a 1:M between Calendar and Phishing and the Calendar table is not a traditional daily calendar. It is a monthly calendar where month index of 1 is the first year and month of data and month index of say 27 is the 27th year and month of data we have.

```
SUMMARIZE(
    Phishing,
    Phishing[Zid],
    Calendar[Month Index],
    "Count", CALCULATE(
        COUNT(Phishing[Zid]),
        < I want to calculate a count between the current month index and month index - 11 >
        Phishing2[Phishing Outcome]= "Fail"
        )
    )
```

The output should look like this:

```
Zid      Month Index   Count
QZ4TIN   27            4
```

This would mean that the user with a Zid of QZ4TIN failed four times between month index 16 and 27.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky to write DAX without having data to test against, but I suspect you want something like

```
FILTER ( 
    ALL ( Calendar ),
    Calendar[Month Index] <= EARLIER ( Calendar[Month Index] ) &&
    Calendar[Month Index] >= EARLIER ( Calendar[Month Index] ) - 11
)
```

Where [EARLIER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/earlier-function-dax) refers to the earlier row context (from the SUMMARIZE rather than the FILTER), not anything to do with dates or time.

You may wish to create a variable before the CALCULATE rather than using EARLIER

```
SUMMARIZE (
    Phishing,
    Phishing[Zid],
    Calendar[Month Index],
    "Count",
        VAR CurrMonth = Calendar[Month Index]
        RETURN
            CALCULATE (
                COUNT ( Phishing[Zid] ),
                FILTER (
                    ALL ( Calendar ),
                    Calendar[Month Index] <= CurrMonth &&
                    Calendar[Month Index] >= CurrMonth - 11
                ),
                Phishing2[Phishing Outcome] = "Fail"
            )
)
```

Comment: Very nice. But, in the RETURN statement, I think I still have the problem where my Phishing table is being filtered for the current person and the current month index, which is essentially a single row. I think I somehow need to 'refilter' my Phishing table so that it contains rows just for the new range of Calendar rows.

Comment: Hmm. Does adding `ALLEXCEPT(Phishing, Phishing[Zid])` to the CALCULATE change anything?

Comment: Yes, but not in a good way. Thank you for your help. You've at least got me farther than I was before. I'm going to try and figure this out.